# Error when trying to test my To-do app functionality

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a To-do app using React. When i run the `npm run dev`command in ubuntu i get this error:

./src/index.js
Attempted import error: './App' does not contain a default export (imported as 'App').

Here is a screenshot of my index.js file.
[index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBH4p.jpg)

Comment: can you post your app.js?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put `export default App` at the end of your App.js file ?